# Definition of atomic measure

Tags: measure-theory, definition

Firstly consider the following definitions:

> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu )$ be a measure space. We say that $A\in \Sigma $ is an **atom** if $\mu (A)>0$ and, given any $B\in \Sigma $
> with $B\subseteq A$, $\mu (B)=\mu (A)$ if, and only if, $\mu (B)\neq 0$. In addition to that, we say that $E,F\in \Sigma$ are **equivalent** if $\mu(E\vartriangle F)=0$.

**My question is**: is the following two definitions equivalent if we assume that $\mu$ is finite?

> **Definition 1:** Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu )$ be a finite measure space. We say that $\mu$ is **atomic** if there's an atom $A\in \Sigma$.

The above definition is given in the book "[A Course in Functional Analysis and Measure Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-92004-7)" (written by Vladimir Kadets). The following definition is in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)#Atomic_measures):

> **Definition 2:** Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu )$ be a finite measure space. We say that $\mu$ is **atomic** if for all $E\in \Sigma $ with $\mu (E)>0$ there's an atom
> $A\in \Sigma $ such that $A\subseteq E$.

---

Unfortunately I wasn't able prove it or find a counterexample. However I was able to prove that, if $\mu$ is finite, then there exists a finite or countable disjoint sequence $A_1,A_2,\cdots$ of atoms of the measure $\mu$ such that any atom of $\mu$ is equivalent to one of the atoms $A_n$.

Comment: No, they are not the same. The first is conceptualizing the idea that there is an atom, while the second the idea that all positive measure of $\mu$ is coming from atoms. $X=[0,1]\cup \{2\}$, $\Sigma$ being the Borel $\sigma$-algebra as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mu$ being the Lebesgue on $[0,1]$ and the counting on $\{2\}$ satisfies the first definition with $A=\{2\}$, but not the second, since $\mu([0,1])=1$ but there are no atoms inside $[0,1]$.

Comment: I am not sure if this answers your question. Consider the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $[0,1]$ and the Dirac $\delta_0$ on $0$. Define the measure $\mu := \lambda + \delta_0$. Then, there is an atom (which is the set $\{0\}$). However, it is not atomic in the sense of definition 2 as $[0.5,1]$ does not contain any atom. I think that Definition 1 means that $\mu$ has an atom, whereas Definition 2 means that $\mu$ consists only of atoms.